# GCC - How should I be formatting this string correctly? Segmentation Fault Error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault error when trying to print out a char array in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printLoop(char args[])
{
  char* p;
  for (*p = *args; *p != '\0'; p++)
  {
    printf("%s", p);
  }
  getchar();
} 

int main()
{
  char *text = "Test";
  printLoop(text);
}
```

I'm receiving:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I've read that it has something to do with me allocating to much space for the array but I don't really understand why I'm getting this.

Comment: Change the `for` in `printLoop` to `for(p = args; *p != '\0'; p++)`. Best of luck.

Comment: Hey, thanks I managed to figure it out in another post but now i'm receiving a format error. Its printing "Testeststt" rather than just "Test". Any idea why?

Comment: You get "Testeststt" because you are printing *the string beginning with p*, rather than *the character pointed to by p*. So you print "Test", then "est", then "st", then "t".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `*p = *args`, you're assigning the value of the character pointed to by `args` to the value of `p`, but you haven't assigned `p`, so you can't dereference it.

You need to change

```
for (*p = *args; *p != '\0'; p++)
```

to

```
for (p = args; *p != '\0'; p++)
```

That assigns the pointer `args` to the pointer `p`.

After you do that, if you're only trying to print `"Test"`, then you can't keep printing the entire string pointed to by `p` in each iteration of the loop.

You need to change

```
printf("%s", p);
```

to

```
printf("%c", *p);
```

or even

```
putchar(*p);
```

Because you want to print the character pointed to by `p`, not the string pointed to by `p`.

Answer (score 2):

After assigning `char *p = args;`, Loop as

```
while(*p != '\0')
```

or

```
for(p = args, *p != '\0' ; p++)
```

and change `printf("%s", *p);` to `printf("%c", *p);`, since you are printing it `char` by `char`. 
Needless to say, increment `p` in loop if used in a `while` loop.

You were using `%s` which is used to print a string at once, so at the first iteration it printed `Test` and then `p` was incremented, it printed `est` and so on.. 
You need to print a `char` pointed by `p`, one `char` at a time.